# Why am I getting a java.sql.SQLException near "@" in my JDBC SQLite database?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, sql-update

I am trying to update values in my SQLite Database. My code is as follows:

```
                   for(Cookie ck:cookie) {
                        if (ck.getName().equals("email")) {
                            s=ck.getValue();
                            System.out.println(s);
                            for(Cookie ce:cookie) {
                                if(ce.getName().equals("name")) {
                                    System.out.println(ce.getValue());
                                    i=PS.executeUpdate("UPDATE Details "+"SET name="+ce.getValue()+" WHERE email="+s);
                                }
                                else if (ce.getName().equals("age")) {
                                    System.out.println(ce.getValue());
                                    i=PS.executeUpdate("UPDATE Details "+"SET age="+ce.getValue()+" WHERE email="+s);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        
                    }
```

Here, I am trying to fetch the **name**, **age** and **email** with the help of `Cookies` and updating those values in the database. Then when I enter the inputs, I get this error (suppose the email is: **abc@gmail.com**):

```
java.sql.SQLException: near "@gmail": syntax error
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:210)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:152)
    at abhishek.Modify.doGet(Modify.java:44)...
```

Comment: You should not concatenate values into a query string. Instead parameterize your statement, and use a prepared statement, set the values on the statement object, and then execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add single quotes around strings in sql.

```
i=PS.executeUpdate("UPDATE Details "+"SET name='"+ce.getValue()+"' WHERE email='"+s+"'");
...
i=PS.executeUpdate("UPDATE Details "+"SET age="+ce.getValue()+" WHERE email='"+s+"'")
```

BTW learn about prepared statements to prevent sql-injection